# symmetric and anti-symmetric (but not necessarily reflexive and transitive)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Q1: Let S:={a,b,c}. How many relations on S are reflexive and symmetric?

Q2: Let S:={a,b,c}. How many relations on S are symmetric and anti-symmetric (but not necessarily reflexive and transitive)?

Comment: Please kindly include your attempt.